# What is the bast way to detect which view to instantiate in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am just wondering what is the best way to know which view to instantiate, in my application I have an individual view for each page and one master view which controls the generic functions and navigating between pages.

There are a couple of different ways that I could detect which page I am on and which view I should instantiate but I wanted some opinions on what others think is best.

So currently my options are:

- To detect via URL
- To detect via ID on containing element

If anyone has any better ideas that would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

I guess I could also add something like this on the HTML page:

```
<script>
    var page_one_view = new PageOneView();
</script>
```

With the correct view being instantiated on each HTML page, but this seems very messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are doing the wrong way, why ?

The backbone component that provides methods for routing client-side pages is **Backbone.Router**, [take a look at the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)

So if you use a view to manage your pages flow, you'll finish up re-implementing a new router with a diffrent approch.

Comment: Ah yes of course I completely forgot about the router, I am pretty new to backbone. Thanks.

Comment: Can you look at this this page for me please, perhaps you can help me out. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199059/backbone-router-not-working-on-page-load